# Search results are not returning from sql query using search button

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to get a search functionality working. When the user clicks in a box and searches something the page should be able to display the results with the word included, otherwise there is a simple message that no result could be found. At the moment nothing is displaying (no errors either) and I do not know why.

Here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

1) On my index.php page there is the search box and search button.

```
<li>
    <div id = "search">
    <form id = "search-form" action="search_results.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name= "find" placeholder= "Search..." />
    <input type="button" name = "search" value="search" />
    </form>
</div> 
</li>
```

2) When the user types what they want, they are taken to search_results.php where the searching happens. A list of product names should be returned if the search was successful.

```
<div class = "main-content">
    <h1> Search Results </h1>
    <?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';
    $output ='';
    if (isset($_get['find'])){
    $searchq = $_get['find'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodname LIKE '%". $searchq . "%'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
    echo "There was no search results !";
}
    else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $prodname = $row['prodname'];
    $output ='<div> '.$prodname.'</div>';
    echo $output;
}
}
} // end of outer if
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format the code using Ctrl+K

Comment: When you have method="post" in your form at PHP you must check for $_POST not for $_get .. p.s you query is 100% unsecured if you directly use data sent from clients without filtering it..

Comment: thanks very much for the swift replies! And thanks for the quick spot Svetlio- works fine now :)

Comment: What happens when you search for `';drop table products;`?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `post` and using the `$_get` in your `search_results.php` file which is wrong method.

As you are using the `post` method in your action you should get the values accordingly

i.e.,

```
if (isset($_POST['find'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['find'];
#Your If Condition
}
else
{
#Your Else Part
}
```